# Three.js mouse variable

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouse

I'm trying to get my sphere to change variables depending on the mouse position. The problem is that I can't even get it to work right, I'm probably doing something wrong, because everytime I try to paste the variable code anywhere the screen just blacks out; this is the code.

What I would like is for the sphere to rotate depending on the mouse positon, but I'm happy if someone can troubleshoot how to add a mouse variable.

I've tryed this without succes, whenever I put the code anywhere within mine the entire window just blackscreened.

```
mouse.x = event.clientX;
```

and

```
var mouse.x = event.clientX;
```

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000044);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);

    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
    scene.add(light2);

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 30, 30);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xEEEEED,
        wireframe: true
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh.position.set(0, 0, -500);
    mesh.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    function render() {
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
</script>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [three.js exmaples](https://threejs.org/examples/). Most include some form of mouse interaction. Here is one ( https://threejs.org/examples/?q=geometry#webgl_geometry_colors ) which responds to mouse movement, rather than dragging. Keep in mind that in most situations, it is easier (more efficient) to move the camera, than it is to move many objects, and that is what a majority of the examples do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [`THREE.OrbitControls`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls).

```
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

```
 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
```

To make it work and to start with a proper initialized camera and mesh position, you should set the camera position out of the center of the world, but you should leave the mesh in the center of the world.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 500 );
```

See the snippet:

```js
var renderer, camera, controls, scene, mesh;

function init() {  

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000044);
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 500 );
    resize();
    window.onresize = resize;
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);
    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
    scene.add(light2);

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 30, 30);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xEEEEED,
        wireframe: true
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh);
}

function resize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function render() {
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005; mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init(); render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, my code is alot cleaner now, however I don't want to use Orbit Controls, I'm looking for mouse controls similar to: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors

But my code just does not recognize the OnDocumentMouseMove(event)
I will ask a seperate question for this

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<script src="Detector.js"></script>
<script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

then include:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.enableZoom = true;
```

Also I notice you don´t have properly set camera, example:

```
camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);
```

I suggest to divide code in sections, and at the end call them.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
init();
initLight();
animate();
requestAnimationFrame(render);
controls.update(); 
});
```